# Get an image url when the user selects the image from a list of their photos

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a list of the user's images displayed, (who has already allowed access to the app).

```
<div class="list inline">
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($photos as $photo) {
        // Extract the pieces of info we need from the requests above
        $id = idx($photo, 'id');
        $picture = idx($photo, 'picture');
        $link = idx($photo, 'link');

        $class = ($i++ % 4 === 0) ? 'first-column' : '';
?>
<li style="background-image: url(<?php echo he($picture); ?>);" class="<?php echo $class; ?>"'
```

I need to allow the user to choose one. When he/she does I can get the unique id or url of that image to load it into a different api embedded into the project through (through src maybe???)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean, but maybe you can download the image local and then use it in any api you want?

```
file_get_contents($picture);
```